# $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{2n}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_{2n+1}$ given $c_{n+2} = \frac{n(n+1)-\lambda}{(n+2)(n+1)}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, ordinary-differential-equations, power-series, legendre-functions

Legendre equation is

$$ (1-x^2) y'' - 2xy' + \lambda y=0$$

We are interested in finding solutions in the range $[-1,1]$. We seek solutions around the ordinary point $x=0$
$$ \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n $$
Since legendre equation has regular singular points at $-1,1$ , this series is guaranteed to converge in $|x|<1$.
Substituting this power series into the differential equation one arrives at the following recursive relation

$$c_{n+2} = \frac{n(n+1)-\lambda}{(n+2)(n+1)}$$

Putting $c_0 = 1$ and $c_1 = 0$ gives the solution $y_1(x)$
Putting $c_0 = 0$ and $c_1 = 1$ gives the solution $y_2(x)$

Now if $\lambda = l(l+1)$ with $l$ a non-negative integer it can be shown that a solution to legendre equation is the legendre polynomial
$$P_l(x) = \frac{1}{2^l l!} \frac{d^l}{dx^l}(x^2-1)^l$$
which is analytic everywhere.

However, if $\lambda$ is not of this form, the series solutions converges at the end points $x=-1,1$ ?  If not, why not?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_function